# Spritekit - applying an acceleration to a physics body

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm working on a project where I have a node affected by gravity. I would like to be able to apply a vertical acceleration to this node without touching gravity. Pretty much like a hot air balloon that I would make go up or down while other objects are still normally affected by gravity.

```
balloon = Vehicle()
balloon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
balloon.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

I tried playing around with `applyForce(_:)` and impulse but what I'd like is a proper acceleration and not a punctual impulse to defy gravity over time! Any suggestion?

Comment: It helps if you show some code that you've already written to see where we can guide you. Otherwise people feel like you want them to design the whole thing for you.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry. I don't have anything really specific to show though. I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are physics fields (`SKFieldNode`), in Sprite Kit.

These provide the ability to influence objects with general forces, like wind, lift, black hole style attraction etc.

You can read about them [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode)

The really important consideration of how they can work is in this [quote](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519774-affectedbygravity):

> Physics bodies with affectedByGravity set to false are still affected
>   by the gravity fields created by linearGravityField(withVector:) and
>   radialGravityField().

But what they forgot to also make clear(er) is that objects influenced by gravity are ALSO influenced by these fields.